# Sharepoint: Update an item when an item is added in another list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

So I had to make a Sharepoint site to inventorize our servers. I have two types of lists (replicated a few times per group, but for this, just consider two lists), one lists servers and has a column 'NICs' which does a lookup on the other list, which lists NICs.

The NICs list has a column 'Server' which does a lookup from the Serverlist. 
A server can also have multiple NICs, but a NIC can only get assigned to one server. I suppose setting the niclists 'server'-column to be unique covers this aspect?

Say I have some items in my NIC-list, 'nic1', 'nic2', 'nic3'. 
If I add a serveritem to the serverlist and I add 'nic1' and 'nic2' to its nic-lookupcolumn, how can I have sharepoint automatically add this new serveritem to 'nic1' and 'nic2''s server-lookupcolumn?

I have investigated workflows, but I haven't found a way to do this via sharepoint itself. All solutions I find suggest coding in ASP.net, but I have no experience with it.

(On a separate note, how do I remove the Server-column from the form for a new nic-item?)

Comment: Hard question: I can only think of two ways: 1. C# coding a Event Receiver [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407274(v=office.14).aspx) or 2. Making a workflow [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-workflow-HA010100591.aspx). For your seperate Note: If you can edit contenttype of your SharePointList, then you can set  the ShowInNewForm Attribute to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharePoint Workflows for this one. All you need to have is SharePoint Designer. There is a specific action called `Update List Item` which allows you to update any list using your workflow or `Create List Item` to create items on a different list. You just need to properly setup the lists and workflows you will be using. You can follow the general rule below:

- If you are updating a list, make sure the child list (or the list you will be updating based from
  another list's value) has a unique reference from your parent list.
- Use the `Update List Item` or `Create List Item` action when an item is added in a list to 
  make sure the workflow is properly triggered.

And since lookups are typically just lists used as a column on another list the same principles above apply when creating the workflow.

For more details on how to use the said workflow action you can go and visit this [link](http://rishijagati.blogspot.com/) and this [link](http://sharepointresourcecenter.com/sharepoint-workflow-actions-create-list-item.html).

Answer (score 0):

you could easily do this using sharepoint designer workflows, you could create a workflow to list a and then in the workflow itself, update/create a new list item for the other list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using EventReceiver. It is pretty easy to code in visual studio.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858%28v=office.14%29.aspx

you can use item creation/update event.